# how to close & auto-lock function windows XP without minimising current program on screen

Tags: windows, windows-xp

How do I close and have the auto-lock function (username login) in place in Windows XP without minimizing the current program on screen?  I just want to push a key and have the auto-lock / user name login there immediately, in case I need to get up and go from my laptop but leave my work up and secure so I can get straight back to the work on return.

Answer (score 4):

`Windows+L` will lock the screen to the user login.

Comment: Ctl+Alt+Del then Enter will do it as well.

Comment: Either of these.  (I'm curious why you need to minimize a window anyway - even if you're doing it from the Start Menu.  Do you have your taskbar not set to always on top?  I didn't think that was possible...usually autohide is enough for most people.  Personally I leave mine alone.)